# Symfony2 generate entities error

Tags: symfony, entities

I'm trying to generate entities from existing tables in database, I keep getting the same error in a particular entity, which is imported from a second database (or entity manager), but I re-created this table in main database to use the same entity manager and get the same error, so I'm lost about what is happening.

This are my commands to generate it:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/MyShop/ProductBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --filter="Product" --em=mysecondaryem
```

*(BTW, is there a way to force exact filter? I only need Product)*
Which seems to be ok:

```
Processing entity "ProductSold"
Processing entity "Product"

Exporting "yml" mapping information to...
```

Then

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import MyShopProductBundle annotation --em=mysecondaryem
```

Which is weird, as it is logging information about all other tables existing in this db but it's only generating the corresponding to "Product" as filtered (only the files ProductSold.php and Product.php do really exist):

```
Importing mapping information from "mysecondaryem" entity manager
  > writing C:\mysite\src\MyShop\ProductBundle/Entity/ProductSold.php
  > writing C:\mysite\src\MyShop\ProductBundle/Entity/Family.php
  > writing C:\mysite\src\MyShop\ProductBundle/Entity/Category.php
  > writing C:\mysite\src\MyShop\ProductBundle/Entity/Item.php
  > writing C:\mysite\src\MyShop\ProductBundle/Entity/Stock.php
  > writing C:\mysite\src\MyShop\ProductBundle/Entity/Product.php
```

Then, in the third step, I get an error:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyShopProductBundle --no-backup

Generating entities for bundle "MyShopProductBundle"
  [RuntimeException]
  Bundle "MyShopProductBundle" does not contain any mapped entities.
doctrine:generate:entities [--path="..."] [--no-backup] name
```

As I sayed, I tried omitting secondary entity manager (replicating tables in my first database) and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the error, I was missing **--force** parameter, first step command should be:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/MyShop/ProductBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force --filter="Product" --em=mysecondaryem
```

Answer (score 1):

You've verified that `C:\mysite\src\MyShop\ProductBundle/Entity/Product.php` has been created, but have you also checked that it actually contains mapped entities ?

Comment: It does exist, and it does contain annotated entities, so I guess they are mapped. I tried to repeat the whole process by hand and in the last step I also get an exception (a different one) `[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException] Class MyShop\ProductBundle\Entity\Product" is not a valid entity or mapped super class` I copied exactly from another valid entity so I'm quite lost. This last _manual_ version has only a subset of all db table fields.